# Solve setup time violation when CLK is same as data input in shift resistor

Tags: circuit-design, error

DSTM7 is same as push button 1 and DSTM8 is same as push button 0. I want shift resister shift when either button is pushed. For example, when push button 1 is pushed and DSTM7 has a pulse and shift resister shift with first element 1 and when push button 0 is pushed and DSTM8 has a pulse and shift resister shift with first element 0.

[image: circurit]

In this circuit in the picture, I input 100101. (DSTM7 indicate 1 and DSTM8 indicate 0). And when new input come, I want to change QA, QB, QC, QD which is LLLL in initial state to become HLLL, LHLL, LLHL, HLLH, LHLL, HLHL in a sequence.

This circuit works well in pspice but I know this cause setup time violation because input SR and CLK is same in 74194 ic. How can I solve this problem without delay ic?

[image: sample output]

This is sample output. This is my first question so please forgive me even if I violate community guide. (Just notice me and I will change my question)

Answer (score 0):

That design should be okay. 74194 has a 5nS setup time, while 7432 has a 10/14 ns propagation delay.  If you use a more modern logic family like 74HC194 & 74HC32 you might find the times are comparable while being much less power hungry. Or perhaps you follow the OR gate with another OR gate to slow it down some more - there are typically 4 in package.